# Postfix: Disable spam filter for outgoing email

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

My Postfix/SpamAssassin setup is sending out emails with headers from SpamAssassin.

How do I stop it?

Whitelisting my network/domain doesn't seem to do the trick.

How do I tell postfix, to use the content filter on incoming emails only?

Comment: Which method of postfix and spamassassin integration do you use?

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is the answer you are looking for, but I'd say I use pipes.
I have a line at the end of `master.cf` starting with `spamassassin` a couple `n`s and `-`s and a `pipe` at the end. I also have `--content-filter=spamassassin` at the end of `smtp`, `submission` and `smtps` if I remember correctly